# SvelteKIt: getting an error "Handler should return a response", though I am returning one?

Tags: httprequest, svelte, sveltekit

I have a simple API endpoint server function that imitates an authorization POST request:

```js
/** @type {import('./$types').RequestHandler} */

import { json, error } from '@sveltejs/kit'

export async function POST({ request }) {
    const data = await request.json()

    if (!data.username || !data.password) {
        return error(400, 'Missing username or password.')
    }

    return json({ username: data.username, id: 1 })
}
```

And a form that uses this function in `+page.svelte`:

```js
async function login() {
        const response = await fetch('/api/auth/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username,
                password
            })
        })
        const resJSON = await response.json()
        console.log('Form submitted', resJSON)
    }
```

But I'm getting an error in the terminal: `Error: Invalid response from route /api/auth/login: handler should return a Response object`.

Am I not returning an object in json({})?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `error()` does not return anything returnable. It, in fact, [returns an exception](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#sveltejs-kit-error) that you must throw so, changing line

```
 return error(400, 'Missing username or password.')
```

To this

```
throw error(400, 'Missing username or password.')
```

Will fix your problem

Comment: Thank you very much! Takes a trained eye to spot these.